# Setting guest access on Xbox Series X

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

I'm going away for several weeks, and have a house-sitter coming to stay.  I would like to set up the Xbox (Series X) so that they can use it, but don't want them to use my profile.

Is it possible to set up a guest account on my Xbox so my house-sitter friend can use it while I'm away?  How can I do this?  It would need to load into that profile each and every time they turn it on (and preferably not have access to my profile)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A single Microsoft account, but two Xbox consoles: I would like to use a different unlock pattern](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405349/a-single-microsoft-account-but-two-xbox-consoles-i-would-like-to-use-a-differe)

Answer (score 1):

I answered a slightly similar question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405349/a-single-microsoft-account-but-two-xbox-consoles-i-would-like-to-use-a-differe) where I mentioned the user of an [Access PIN](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/family-online-safety/passkey-guest-key/setup-guest-key-limits).  This may achieve what you are looking for.

The PIN allows guests to use the console without having to sign in to your account:

> An access PIN is different from a guest account. An access PIN is a reusable passcode that allows guests to use your console without requiring you to sign in to your Microsoft account. A temporary access account can only be created while you’re signed in, and it’s deleted as soon as you or your guest signs out.

You can then [restrict the content](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/family-online-safety/online-safety/restrict-content-access-when-noone-signed-in) they have access to when using the console in this manner by:

> After you create your access PIN, you can set parameters around what content can be viewed on your console when no one is signed in.
>
> 1. Press the Xbox button to open the guide.
> 2. Go to Profile & system > Settings > System > Access restrictions.
> 3. Select Access to content.
> 4. Select the age-appropriate content level that you want to allow for your guests.